# Parameter not shared between C# events

Tags: c#

I'm trying to control a form using DataSelector and button.

```
public void DataSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    switch (DataSelector.SelectedIndex) {
        case 0:
            byte[] param1 = {
                0x00, 0x01
            };
            //some code here 
            break;
        case 1:
            byte[] param1 = {
                0x00, 0x02
            };
            //some code here 
            break;
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Dictionary < string, object > postParameters = new Dictionary < string, object > ();

    postParameters.Add("param1", param1);
}
```

However this gives me error message,param1 does not exist in the current context.
I have tried declare param1 public,its ok to declare outside as

```
public byte[] param1={0x00,0x01};
```

but when I set `param1={0x00,0x02};` in Datasector event,it says got syntax error,missing expression term { ,

Adding `DataSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);` in button1 click event also not helping...

Can anyone tell me what happened?
Thanks!

Comment: Try `param1=new byte[] {0x00,0x02};` in the `DataSelector_SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: When you declare a variable inside a method, that variable only exists within the scope of that method - you can't use it from another one.

Comment: declare a class level `private` variable, and you can reuse it.

Comment: You can't assign values this way param1={0x00,0x02}; once the variable is initialized.

Comment: One could always use `new Byte[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share a value between two different methods you need to either use a class-level field or don't use two different methods.

The standard approach is to use a field. This is what your code would look like:

```
    private Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = null;
    private byte[] param1 = null;

    private void DataSelector_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (DataSelector.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                param1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 };
                //some code here 
                break;
            case 1:
                param1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x02 };
                //some code here 
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postParameters.Add("param1", param1);
    }
```

This is fine, but it does mean that you have to manage fields that could get manipulated by other parts of your code.

It is better now to encapsulate all the logic within a single method using anonymous methods.

Your code could look like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = null;
        byte[] param1 = null;

        DataSelector.SelectedIndexChanged += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            switch (DataSelector.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    param1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01 };
                    //some code here 
                    break;
                case 1:
                    param1 = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x02 };
                    //some code here 
                    break;
            }
        };

        button1.Click += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            postParameters.Add("param1", param1);
        };
    }
```